# Gazebo Contacts Bumper

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to get position of a contact with respect to
to frame of the link that is in contact?

I am using Gazebo 1.9 and ROS Indigo.
I am getting contact positions wrt world frame.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205396/gazebo-contacts-bumper/) by [Nomad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19317/nomad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Put your contact into a `geometry_msgs/PointStamped` and set the frame_id to world, then use tf transformPoint to transform the point into the link frame.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nomad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19317/nomad/) on 2015-03-23**:
Thank you!
One comment is that the /tf should be publishing data at sufficient rate.
Use rostopic hz /tf to see the rate. Gazebo publishes link states at 1kHz by default.
But using tf methods simplifies transformations.